# How to read system time zone of an Android device from Espresso

Tags: adb, android-espresso

I need to write an Espresso test case to read the device time zone. I know there is an **adb shell command** to output device timestamp on a command shell (e.g.):

```
c:\>adb shell date
Mon Aug  8 17:46:23 EDT 2022
```

From where I could grab the time zone 'EDT'.
But, how to do it in Espresso ?
I have tried the above **adb shell command** in an Espresso code as below, but it does nothing but completes the test run.

Here is my sample code which I tried:

```
package com.mycompany.ui.activity;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.junit.Test;

public class FindTimeZone {

    @Test
    public void findTimeZone() throws InterruptedException {

        String command = "cmd.exe /c adb shell date";
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        } catch (
                IOException ignored) {
        }

    }//findTimeZone()
}//class FindTimeZone
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
TimeZone.getDefault();
```

See https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone#getDefault()

Comment: your suggested answer outputs the TZ of the host not the connected device.

Comment: You mentioned from Espresso not from the host